# HtmlHelper.Button(..., string onClickMethod, ...) HTML-encodes single-quotes!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm upgrading an old project from MVC 1.0 to MVC 3.0 (yes, it's that old), and I've run into an issue where calling HtmlHelper.Button(..., onClickMethod, ...) HTML-encodes single quotes into `&#39;`

I can see how this would not be an issue if onClickMethod was just the name of a method to be called in javascript, however this is how we are using it:

```
return helper.Button(name, buttonText, HtmlButtonType.Button,
    string.Format("window.location='{0}'", url));
```

which obviously is now broken.

Is there any way to bypass this encoding?  I can see hacking it by changing the return type of the method to string, and doing:

```
return string.Format(helper.Button(name, buttonText, HtmlButtonType.Button,
    "window.location={0}").ToString(), "'" + url + "'");
```

but this is more or less a hack, and not elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the `&#39;` should work. Even though the document stream contains the encoded value the browser unencodes it when it builds the DOM. You can use a DOM inspection tool to see yourself.

If I put the following on a page I see the alert box just fine upon click:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert(&#39;Hello&#39;);" />
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  It just looks weird in the unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the URI class to convert html codes into regular text

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString(string);
```